# Text to speech software with option to change language on the fly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, speech-synthesis

Is there a TTS software for Ubuntu that has language recognition?

Given the input file:

```
this is English.

dies ist Deutsch.
```

The program needs to speak out the first sentence in English and the second one in German.

So we would require the software to speak English as English and German as German.